# .net mvc + jquery.confirm

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-confirm

i'm using .net MVC with [jquery.confirm](http://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/#ajaxloading)
and i have some problem:

i want to show a dialog such as Login Dialog, it's easy to do like this:

```
        $.dialog({
        title: 'Login',
        content: 'url:/Account/Login'
    });
```

this is a good way for me because i can also visit "myweb/Account/Login" to access Login page and it's easy to write or debug codes.

but when i close the dialog by click the "X" button, this page lose response, i'm thinking it's because when the dialog try to get url "/Account/Login", it cause server redirecting.

i have to do like this:

```
        $.confirm({
        title: 'Login',
        content: 'url:/Account/Login',
        onClose: function () {
            //window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index")';
            //this can solve my problem but i don't want to do like this,because it cause some data missing of Index page.
        }
    });
```

Anyone who can helps me? Thank a lot!!!

Comment: so you are displaying login form in a JQuery confirm box right ?

Comment: its better to call a ajax request when Model is closed

Comment: yes, i think i found the reason: when i open the console, i found an error: $.confirm is not a function